# Magento 2.3: CRON job is not working in custom module

Tags: magento2.3, cron, csv

I have created a module for collecting customer data from the Magento database and sending them as a CSV file to another server by hitting the controller URL in browser.

Now, I want it to be send automatically so that I want to set a CRON job.

So in order to create the CRON job, I have referred the below tutorial:

https://www.mageplaza.com/devdocs/magento-2-create-cron-job/

However, when I run the cron, the file is not being send to another server. But, when I check the log file, I can see the CRON was ran successfully.

I'm not sure what am I missing. Could anyone please guide me?

Your help will be appreciated!

Comment: Please add your logic how you implemented file one server to new server.

Comment: As of now, I just followed the things in the mentioned URL. Can you please point me out how to send the file to another server that would be very helpful for me?

Comment: have you add this code $writer = new \Zend\Log\Writer\Stream(BP . '/var/log/cron.log');
  $logger = new \Zend\Log\Logger();
  $logger->addWriter($writer);
  $logger->info(__METHOD__);

Comment: if yes then check cron.log files in var folder.

Comment: I have added that code and in the log file, I can see that the cron job was ran successfully. However, the file is not received in another server.

Comment: above code for not sending files it is create cron.log file in var folder

Comment: Yes, you're right. So, could you please tell me how to create a cron job to send a file?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/105603/discussion-between-jinesh-and-siva).